# What is the name of a python installation?

Tags: python

I have several python installations in my PC.

[image]

How do I find out which name adresses which python installation e.g. when I want to use `pip`: `python -m pip install package` or `py -m pip install package` or `py3 -m pip install package`

Comment: You will want to uninstall some of them.

Comment: `pip --version` will display the specific version of Python that it works with.

Comment: @BrainFlooder: Sure, cleaning up would help. But in this case i can not get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, use `where` to figure out which actual executable is run:

```
where python
```

(The [`py` launcher may internally decide on another version](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) as requested, so `where py` will probably not help that much.)

To expand on the discussion in the comments:

Your `python -m pip ...` uses the `python`(.exe) that `where python` reveals; instead of just `python` you can use any other `python.exe`. The same stands for pythons in virtualenvs.

Comment: `Where python` returns the paths to one python installation. In my case: `C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe` and `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`. I want to use the `pip` command on all of my installations: How do I can I say `python pip install package` for python 3.7.4 and for python 3.9.5?

Comment: Well, those paths are clearly visible in the dropdown in your screenshot, and you're already using `python -m pip` according to your original post. `C:\some\other\python.exe -m pip ...`

Comment: Oh, I did not know that I could just use the path instead for `python`. That is the answer to what I was looking for.

Comment: @aehruesch Glad I could help. I edited that detail into the answer too, if you'd care to mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

***It Is Different For "Every Platforms/OS .***

> Windows

```
where python
```

**You Have to Type This in Your Powershell or Command Prompt .
Then It Will Show You The Right Path And Find That Path in Vscode And Select IT .**

> Mac

**for python3**

```
which python3
```

**for python2**

```
which python
```

**You Have to Type This in Your Terminal .
Then It Will Show You The Right Path And Find That Path in Vscode And Select IT .**

> Linux

**for python3**

```
which python3
```

**for python2**

```
which python
```

**You Have to Type This in Your Terminal .
Then It Will Show You The Right Path And Find That Path in Vscode And Select IT .**

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the question I know the paths of the different installation. So instead of writing `python -m pip install package` I can also write: `[path to the python installation] -m pip install package`.

Example: `"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" -m pip install package`